# Split string in column and create new columns with the output (r)

Tags: r, strsplit

How do I split the first column into 2 components (e.g., 01 & run1) and create 2 other columns to store that information?

```
P = c('01_run1', '01_run2', '02_run1', '02_run2')
Score = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
df = data.frame(P, Score)

        P Score 
1 01_run1     1
2 01_run2     2
3 02_run1     3
4 02_run2     4
```

End Product

```
            P Score Number  Run
    1 01_run1     1     01 run1
    2 01_run2     2     01 run2
    3 02_run1     3     02 run1
    4 02_run2     4     02 run2
```

I can use strsplit() with split = '_' to separate the 2 components but is there another way to create the 2 columns other than using loops (which many have advised not to do so in r?)

Comment: several ways, one would be: `do.call(rbind, strsplit(P, "_"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `sub` here, for one base R option:

```
df$Number <- sub("_.*$", "", df$P)
df$Run    <- sub("^.*_", "", df$P)
```

[image]

### Demo

The first call to `sub` uses the pattern `_.*$` and replaces with empty string (i.e. deletes what is matched).  What this would match is everything from underscore until the end of the string.  Similarly, the second call to sub uses the pattern `^.*_`, which would remove everything *before* and including the underscore.  In both cases, it would leave us with the data we want.

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Do you mind explaining what the different parameters mean?

Comment: why have you added a picture of the outcome instead of code formatted r output?

Comment: @AndreElrico Ooh...the pretty pictures!  I can't help myself! :~P

Comment: @TYL its called **regular expressions**. Learn as much as possible about it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
df <- df %>% separate(P, c("Number", "Run"), "_", remove = FALSE) %>% select(P, Score, Number, Run)
```